# error: php artisan db:seed Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

when i run:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

i get this error, the quantity field is refered into the categories class, table, however i do not know what to do since in the course i am that error does not happen, for that i am asking for help here in order to clarify how to solve this error (i am new in laravel):

```
     Illuminate\Database\QueryException
    
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value 


SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (commodi, Velit aliquid ut alias esse aut., 2021-08-02 21:18:52, 2021-08-02 21:18:52))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

      +16 vendor frames
  17  database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:38
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::create()

      +22 vendor frames
  40  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

this is the categories factory where the error happens, in the quantity field:

```
<?php

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description', 1000);
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->string('status')->default(Product::PRODUCTO_NO_DISPONIBLE);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

what should i do? i am new on this

thank you in foward for any support

Comment: You are missing a value for `quantity`, you must either add it in the seeder or you have to update your schema to be something like `$table->integer('quantity')->unsigned()->default(0);`. Also, you can write that line a little better: `$table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(0);`.

Answer (score 2):

That means you are trying to seed data to a table but you are missing a column called `quantity`, this column don't have a default value or is not `nullable`, so you should fake its value in the `factory` class or you can put a default value to it in the migration file like this:

```
$table->integer('quantity')->unsigned()->default(1);
```

Comment: Bad advise. ->nullable() must be here.

Comment: its just explanation not advice , i told him to add quantity value to factory class or use default value in migration

Comment: $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned()->default(0);

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'quantity' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (veniam, Aspernatur laborum voluptatem placeat perferendis odio rerum maxime. Sit eius qui quidem et quis id error., 2021-08-04 01:58:24, 2021-08-04 01:58:24))

Comment: added deault value and still having the same error, added default value for all the quantity field table and still having the same error